# I would like to get clarified between below two constructs?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

```
loop do
  token = Devise.friendly_token
  break token unless User.where(authentication_token: token).first
end  

loop do
  token = Devise.friendly_token
  break token unless self.class.unscoped.where(authentication_token: token).first
end
```

I'm a newbie to ruby and it's rails so, hoping you guys will not downvote my question, since I google around but could not understand between differences.

Comment: the only real difference is `unscoped`. We cant know if you need to disable default scopes

Answer (score 2):

The difference is `User.where` vs `self.class.unscoped`. They do the same thing essentially.

In the first construct the class name `User` is hardcoded into the expression. So the construct will only call `where` on the User class. And the User class has to respond to the `where` message; it must have a class method called `where`.

In the second construct the class name is derived. In Ruby, `self` refers to the instance you are currently working within. If you call `self.class` inside an instance, you get the class name of the instance. For example:

```
apple = Apple.new
puts apple.class.name
# => "Apple"
```

So the second construct can be used inside any class.

The last difference is the [`unscoped`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/unscoped/class) call. This is an ActiveRecord method that removes any defined scopes on a class. Think of it like "remove any filters" before finding records where authentication_token equals token.

I believe `unscoped` was [deprecated](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/unscoped/class).

Comment: No they dont do the same thing, `unscoped` removes default filters, which could be a big deal

Comment: @apneadiving I was in the middle of editing my answer when you left your comment.

Answer (score 1):

Given you are in the class User e.g. in user.rb self.class maps to User. So the difference is actually another scope added to the where clause:

```
class User
  def some_method_to_find_token
    loop do
      token = Devise.friendly_token
      break token unless User.where(authentication_token: token).first
    end  
  end 

  def some_other_method_to_find_token
    loop do
      token = Devise.friendly_token
      break token unless User.unscoped.where(authentication_token: token).first
    end 
  end
end
```

I guess the intention is to create a new token if no token exists. And there probably is a default scope in place which probably filters out deleted_users. Not a really good coding example actually. The first loop is unnecessary as you always have to check if this token is set to a deleted user anyways.

```
class User
  def new_untaken_token
    loop do
      token = Devise.friendly_token
      break token unless User.unscoped.exists?(authentication_token: token)
    end  
  end 
end
```

This could also be written recursivly:

```
class User
  def new_untaken_token
    token = Devise.friendly_token                         # Create a new token
    if User.unscoped.exists?(authentication_token: token) # check if it exists
      new_untaken_token                                   # find another one
    else
      token                                               # use token
    end
  end 
end
```

Comment: Thanks Milan, for detailed answer but i'm not clear due to poor english understanding, both the construct basically checks for token uniqueness throught the users in db including deleted users too(mine constructs), but code provided by you checks only in existing users, mi right or again i misunderstood ? sorry for long gossip.